# Asp.net/Openlayers4: how Can I deblurr a canvas image?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, openlayers

I'm working on an asp.net project. I'm trying to take an image of the map using the following code:

```
    map.once('postcompose', function (event) {

            var img = document.getElementById("source");

            event.context.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, event.context.canvas.width / 2 - img.width / 2, (event.context.canvas.height / 2 - img.height / 2)-20);
            var canvas = event.context.canvas;

            canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob,1);
                reader.onloadend = function () {

                    base64data = reader.result;
                    sendImage(base64data);

                }
```

The image that i have is blurred, how can i deblurr it ?
The map lines are thinner than they appear in the image. Once i click the print button the lines become thicker

[image]

Comment: If you add `map.on('postcompose',function() {console.log(new Date().getTime())});` to your code will will probably see there are multiple postcompose events fired as the map renders (for the same simple map I get between 5 and 10).  Waiting for the final image may give a better result than using the first.

Comment: How to wait for the final image?

Comment: In my test a series of postcompose events seems to fire less than 500ms apart as the map renders.  Maybe set a timeout for 500ms on an event, if there is another event cancel and reset the timeout.  When the timeout eventually fires the map will have been stable for 500ms and should be good to print.