# Asp.net/Openlayers4 : Is there a chance that a map image would be exported from website without distortion and bluing?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, openlayers

I'm trying to export a map image from an asp.net website. The image is distorted as described and shown in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448318/asp-net-openlayers4-how-can-i-deblurr-a-canvas-image)

I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might get a better effect by turning off canvas smoothing in the precompose event, although it mostly benefits raster layers when zoomed in beyond the max zoom of the source as in this sample http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/smoothing.html

```
map.on('precompose', function(evt) {
  evt.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
});
```

Comment: On precompose the picture is taken empty without layers, I tried to turn off canvas smoothing in the precompose and the postcompose  event and it didn't work

Comment: Setting the smoothing option must be done on precompose, before anything is rendered.  Then the layers compose smoothly (maybe) but it won't be to use until postcompose (postrender on OL5).